# How to move to end of line in vim with virtualedit=all and set wrap

Tags: vim

How to move to end of a screen line in vim with `set virtualedit=all` and `set wrap` when a long line is splited into several screen lines?

I want a shortcut, `l` not count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g$` brings you to the end of the current *screen line*. You're right that `:set virtualedit=all` changes that to the last *possible* screen column, even if that doesn't physically exist in the file (which is what virtual edit is about). With normal, single-space word spacing, you could correct that via `gEl` (back to end of last word + right), but for the general case, you will have to (temporarily) unset `'virtualedit'`. This shortcut works:

```
g$:set ve= ve=all<CR>
```

Comment: I guess he wants something like `L`, to the bottom of screen, `L` doesn't work if one long line in window though. Maybe I didn't get him right.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat: Your answer is great!

Answer (score -1):

did you try with  `$` ?

$ Move to the end of the line.